# mediaelement.js + bootstrap carousel : stop or pause video when slide

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have got a problem with mediaelement.js and bootstrap carousel

How to pause or stop the current video when I slide to another slide that contains an image?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('video').mediaelementplayer({
startVolume: 0.5,
enableAutosize: true,
features: ['playpause','volume','fullscreen'],
pauseOtherPlayers: true,});});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fcerret/7nsdkdq1/7/

Thx a lot for help

Comment: Did you resolve this issue by any mean?